# C++: Convert Win32 textbox char -> int -> char and put back in another textbox

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

I want to accept text input using a text box, then change the characters to integers and do fun math with my integers, and then put them back into a char array to be printed in another text box.

Here is my code:

```
int len = GetWindowTextLength(textbox) + 1;
char* text = new char[len];
GetWindowText(textbox, &text[0], len);

int x = 0;
int INTmessage[len];
int ENClen = (len * 2);
char ENCmessage[ENClen];

while (x < len) {
    INTmessage[x] = int(text[x]) - 32;
    x++;
}

int z = 0;
int y = 0;

while (z < ENClen) {
    ENCmessage[z] = (INTmessage[y] % 9);
    ENCmessage[z + 1] = (INTmessage[y] % 10);

    z += 2;
    y++;
}

SetWindowText(textreturn, "");
SetWindowText(textreturn, ENCmessage[0]);
```

The last line displays a compiler error:

> invalid conversion from 'char' to LPCSTR.

Comment: *I know that it should be &ENCmessage* - I'm not sure what makes you think that.  Sounds like you're a bit confused about what `&` does.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you have to call `delete[] text` to free the memory which was allocated with `char* text = new char[len];`. Also you are using variable length array in some places (which is supported in GCC, but not in Visual Studio), so you could just put `char text[len];` and not worry about freeing memory.

Comment: *"My current problem is with getting the correct data type conversions happening before and after I do the math."* - Well then, ask **that** question, and leave out redundant code and redundant talk (knowing what this programming is supposed to be doing at some point is irrelevant to the problem). Your question should be one paragraph (two at most), and a few lines of code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], the problem and expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please specify What you mean by 'I don't know why this does not work'. One Error in your code is this:

```
//This line is incorrect because it converts an address to integer, which has no relation to value of textbox, making decryption impossible.
INTmessage[x] = int(&text[x]) - 32;
//Maybe you may want to use this code: 
INTmessage[x] = int(text[x]) - 32;
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line fails because you are passing a single `char` to `SetWindowText()` (accessing `ENCmessage[0]` returns the first `char` in the `ENCmessage` array).  `SetWindowText()` expects a `char*` pointer to a null-terminated string instead.  You can drop the `[0]`:

```
SetWindowText(textreturn, ENCmessage);
```

Just make sure that `ENCmessage` contains a null character after your digit characters.

That being said, your code can be re-written to something more like this:

```
int len = GetWindowTextLength(textbox) + 1;
char* text = new char[len];
len = GetWindowText(textbox, text, len);

int *INTmessage = new int[len];
for(int x = 0; x < len; ++x) {
    INTmessage[x] = int(text[x]) - 32;
}

int ENClen = (len * 2) + 1;
char *ENCmessage = new char[ENClen];

for(int x = 0, y = 0; x < len; ++x, y += 2) {
    ENCmessage[y] = (INTmessage[x] % 9);
    ENCmessage[y + 1] = (INTmessage[x] % 10);
}
ENCmessage[ENCLen-1] = '\0';

SetWindowText(textreturn, ENCmessage);

delete[] INTmessage;
delete[] ENCmessage;
delete[] text;
```

Or, since you tagged the question as C++, like this instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int len = GetWindowTextLength(textbox) + 1;
std::string text;
text.resize(len);
len = GetWindowText(textbox, &text[0], len);

std::vector<int> INTmessage(len);

for(int x = 0; x < len; ++x) {
    INTmessage[x] = int(text[x]) - 32;
}

int ENClen = (len * 2);
std::string ENCmessage;
ENCmessage.resize(ENClen);

for (int x = 0; y = 0; x < len; ++x, y += 2) {
    ENCmessage[y] = (INTmessage[x] % 9);
    ENCmessage[y + 1] = (INTmessage[x] % 10);
}

SetWindowText(textreturn, ENCmessage.c_str());
```